# AngularJS - Dealing with properties file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to read a properties file in angular, It's neccesary to have this file at the root of my project without any kind of angular stuffs, just a simple file, like java.

This is what I'm doing.

Creating a angular.properties file.

**angular.properties**

```
{ 
    "url": "http://localhost"
}
```

This is my controller where I invoke my service method:

**controller**

```
captchaService                  
    .all()                      
    .then(function(data) {      
        ...
    }, function (data) {
        ...
});
```

This is my service class:

**service**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.service', [])

.factory('myService',
    ['$http', '$q',
    function ($http, $q) {

        var _URL = "";

        function getValuesFromProperties() {

            $http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : 'angular.properties'
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                _URL = data.url;
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                ...
            });

        }

        function all() {

            getValuesFromProperties();

            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                promise = deferred.promise;

            sessionStorage.removeItem('X_CAPTCHA_TOKEN');

            $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : _URL
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                ...
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                ...
            });

            return promise; 
        }

        return {
            all : all,
            getValuesFromProperties : getValuesFromProperties
        };

    }]);
```

But here in my services class I have two $http running on an asynchronous way for that reason I can not get the value of `url` everything else works perfect. How can resolve this? Maybe there is another way to do this. I don't want to create a constant class because this file it's placed at the root of the project and it will be configure for others, they don't need to enter inside a lot of folders and check the code, search and edit. Any idea?

Comment: Do you use grunt?  If so, I have accomplished this task using the grunt plugins grunt-ng-constant and grunt-properties-reader.  During the grunt build, it generates an angular module based on the properties in the configuration file, and then you can simply depend on that module and inject the constants wherever you need them within the angular app.

Comment: @DavidA thanks for your comment, I've read ng-constant very nice plugin! I'll probably use it in the future of my project, but reading the article about it, the values for my constants in ENV or PRODUCTION mode, are setting on a very complex file FOR a simple user (not me or you), it's getting inside my packages and edit values very carefully for someone that it is not very good on javascript or angular. For that reason I'm trying to make it simple FOR a normal "user/worker" that will update some variables.

Comment: Then I can think of 2 solutions... make getValuesFromProperties return a promise, and then within all, wait on the promise and only do the $http request once it is resolved.  If you have other code that depends on those properties, you will have to handle the promise everywhere.  Alternatively, you might consider using something like angular-deferred-bootstrap and delay even initializing angular until you have retrieved the properties file, then you know it is always available and you don't have to work around the async issues.